# Active Record в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет! Нужно внести небольшие изменения в сайт, а он на Yii, с ним я к сожалению не знаком. Добавил новое поле в таблицу, но когда попытался обратится к этому полю через модель Active Record, мне выдаёт 500 ошибку, что такого свойства у объекта нет. Куда ещё добавить мне поле? Должен наверное быть какой-то массив с полями таблицы?

**Проблема решена:**
После того как я скачал к себе сайт и поиском по файлам поискал поля, я увидел папку `app/runtime/cache`
И тут я сразу понял в чём дело!) Почистил содержимое папки и всё заработало!) Всем спасибо!)

Comment: А мануалы там не пробовали читать?

Comment: В том то и дело, что читал. Там написано, что всё автоматически. Поле в таблице есть - оно и создаётся в моделе.

Comment: Может надо миграцию создать и мигрировать, не?

Comment: Давно не работал с 1й версией Yii. Проверьте что вы добавили правила валидации нового поля в rules() вашего ActiveRecord

Comment: @iproger покажите код

Comment: Yii не видит такого поля в таблице. Перепровьте еще раз корректность указания вплоть до символов и что проект подключен к верной базе. Всякое бывает. И судя по логу - никаких промежуточных вставок от сторонних разработчиков там нет, там только чистая AR от Yii.

Comment: Да уже пробовал переименовать таблицу - сайт падал, значит таблица точно та. Уже прям копировал название поля из дампа этой таблицы, ничего не меняется. Ну а может быть такое, что просто где-то перечислены поля, которые загружаются, не "*", а перечислены через запятую?

Comment: Перехожу к крайним мерам. Скачаю весь сайт, и сделаю поиск по всем файлам одного из поля. И если список этих полей есть - то он найдётся) А он, я уверен на 95%, есть)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала можно в index.php поставить DEBUG в true и можно будет посмотреть в чем именно заключается ошибка.
И поле создается в модели при генерации ее через Gii (автоматический генератор кода). Структуру таблицы, код модели и кусок кода, где обращаешься к свойству - все в студию.
И да, мануалы в Yii и гайд - просто сказка. Рекомендую :)

UPD:

```html
    echo  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
          CMap::mergeArray(array(
         'attribute' => 'end_time_edits_for_applications_fulltime', 
         'model' => $model),  
$CJuiDatePicker_default_options), true);
```

Comment: Да нету ничего в мануале. Прочитал уже и на английском и на русском про этот Active Record. Всё сделал правильно. Подикась костылём каким-нибудь что-то испортили. Думал сейчас знатоки скажут, что конфиг должен быть где-то, а нет :( Значит в коде где-то проблема. Дебаг ничего нормального не показал. Сделал var_dump модели, ну нету там этого свойства :(

Comment: В rules задаются только правила валидации. Вопрос не в том. Выложи скрин ошибки.

Comment: relations - это связи с другими моделями. И тоже не должно иметь отношение к тому, что у тебя нету свойства в объекте.

Comment: Я в курсе, но это единственное, что вообще имеет отношение какое-либо к запросам SQL. И даже нету никаких columns и дальше список столбиков. Ужас просто, что уже на таком этапе какие-то проблемы. Надеюсь, это из-за разработчиков сайта, а не из-за Yii. Потому что хочу изучать этот фреймворк, а он меня уже раздражает. Zend, Phalcon - ни капли моих нервов не съели. Всё было адекватно.

Comment: Чувак, что имеет отношение к ошибке в данном случае - так это реальный лог ошибки. :) А фреймворк учи. И раздражает он тебя только потому, что ты не можешь дать корректное описание проблемы, чтобы тебе помогли ее решить. Где лог? :)

Comment: Выше писал же. А структура таблицы где?

Comment: Лог кинул, структура слишком большая, она только зассорит, я уверен в структуре, там не может быть ничего плохого. Лог к сожалению ни о чём не говорит( Посмотрите,пожалуйста, может Вы увидите что-то

Comment: Имена свойств разные.   "SchoolProjPassport.end_time_edits_for_applications" - такое имя пишется в ошибке, а у тебя в коде свойство называется 'end_time_edits_for_applications_fulltime'. Проверь имена свойств в базе, модели, контроллере. Найди именно то свойство на которое ругается. Я не уверен, что ругается на код во вьюхе, код которой в вопросе.

Comment: Я просто добавил два поля, и ругаться начинает на то, которое первее. А так и то и то поле есть(

Comment: Тогда тем более не ясно где корень зла. Тогда проверяй дедовским методом так: ставь die('111'); перед тем, как используешь и смотри в браузер. А потом после того, как используешь. Если в первом случае видишь три единицы, а во втором ошибку - это и есть проблемная строка.

Comment: Да в курсе я о таких методах отладки, проблемной строкой является как раз echo widjet... НО на деле проблема не в ней, а в том, что запрос сам по себе по  коду выделяет не все поля, а только назначенные.

Comment: Попробуй вставить в массив конфигов виджета свойство 'model' как показано выше в апдейте ответа.

Comment: Там и так в $CJuiDatePicker_default_options всё продумано :) Оказывается во всём был виноват кэш объектов) Странно, что мне сразу об этом здесь не сказали)) Спасибо за старания!)